# What is the difference between an Insulator and a Dielectric?

Tags: insulator

Many will say it is Dielectrics are used to store the electric charges, while insulators are used to block the flow of electric charges.  Yet the only difference often is the dielectric constant.

So why do engineers answer there is a difference between an Insulator and a Dielectric?

In this context, I mean an electrical insulator.

Secondary bonus points if you can answer why the differences may be either irrational. illogical or nonlinear.

Comment: I thought it was just intent.

Comment: yes I agree but some sites post incorrect information where the only differences are parameters. Only the electrolytic are different and like batteries, have polarized oxidation on the anode.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand it all dielectric materials are insulators. However not all insulators are dielectric materials. I think the main difference it the polarisation of the electric field that can help them act as a capacitor.

With an insulator (e.g. rubber you can't really store electric charge).

I found the following [chart in circuitglobe.com](https://circuitglobe.com/difference-between-dielectric-and-insulator.html),which I found to be relevant.

[image]

Comment: My experience tells me these properties apply to both columns except the electrolytic are polarized insulators due to the polarized conductor oxidation with the electrolyte.  Both have the same properties in any value. But application engineers tend to prefer one term over the other.

Comment: I believe only differences are not all insulators=dielectrics are electrolytic. I contacted the company whom listed this page for their rebuttal or references to justify its accuracy. Thus only the fabrication methods are different within the insulation umbrella and thus all these properties apply to both except electrolytics are polarized.  All insulators be they rubber air or water can store dielectric charges.

Comment: I don't understand how vacuum can be classified as a dielectric rather than an insulator. How do you polarize a vacuum?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  Time to recalibrate your understanding of dielectrics . Dk=1.000 is in a vacuum https://omnexus.specialchem.com/polymer-properties/properties/dielectric-constant

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 That's not the point...I understand that a vacuum has a dielectric constant. This answer implies that vacuum is a dielectric **because** it can be polarized in an electric field. In other words, the definition of "dielectric" requires that the material can be polarized. So, how does one polarize a vacuum?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson. what made you believe there were no charged particles in a vacuum? There is just no air.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson ??

Answer (score 1):

Well, they are basically the same, with the exception of electrolytes or semiconductors.

The use of these terms is more a matter of functionality.

If used to insulate only, with no difference of the dielectric parameters, "Insulator" will be more adequate term while if dielectric parameters affect other properties of the structure (like RF cable characteristic impedance), the term "Dielectric" will be more adequate.

However, both terms can be interchanged, like when only the mechanical description matters.

Edited:

For insulation, the significant parameters are breakdown voltage and leakage resistance.
For RF applications, the significant parameters would be relative dielectric constant and loss factor.
But the commpn feature is that they have zero (or almost zero) conductivity.

It's like the difference in how one calls his wife. Weather he calls her hunney or sweaty, at the end he takes the garbage out.

Comment: I agree but would say they are equivalent words with multiple implied properties.  They are the opposite of conductors, insulate and have a dielectric value. 

The fact is,  every material that is not classified as a conductor has a dielectric constant, (Dk).  

Even air matches both labels although slightly more than unity relative to a vacuum.  Even semiconductors have Dk when not in the conducting mode.

Comment: Either a material is  a) CONDUCTOR, b) INSULATOR, or c) SEMICONDUCTOR.  The choice between a) & b) $$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$  I believe it depends on Rp vs -X(s)  for  a poor conductor vs a leaky (R) insulator